# Concept of using download service in android

Tags: android

I want to create a service to download files in background. I've seen some samples to do this. When service created it will retrieve array of urls to download, But I want to add dynamically urls to give service and seem I should restart service for getting new urls. Does exits better idea to get new urls concurrently for Download?

Answer (score 0):

Use following Method , It will solve your problem

```
public void startDownload(String URL) {

    DownloadManager mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(URL);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Download_Uri);

        // Restrict the types of networks over which this download may
        // proceed.
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        // Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming
        // connection.
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        // Set the title of this download, to be displayed in
        // notifications (if enabled).
        request.setTitle("Question Answer Updates");
        // Set a description of this download, to be displayed in
        // notifications (if enabled)
        request.setDescription("");
        // Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path
        // within the application's external files directory
        // request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"CountryList.json");

        // Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
    downloadReference   downloadReference = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
```